# Wordpress Admin page not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed WordPress on EC2 with the MySQL database running on Amazon RDS.

The homepage gets displayed correctly but when I try to login into the admin panel, I get an error.

Here the sequence of steps:

1. I go to `http://{ec2-ip-address}/wp-login.php`
2. I insert username and password
3. I get redirected to `http://{ec2-ip-address}/{ec2-ip-address}/wp-admin/` with an error message `"Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server."`
4. If I change the address to `http://{ec2-ip-address}/wp-admin/` (removing the duplication) I can enter the admin panel but the CSS seems broken (see the attached screenshot)

[image]

Looking around I have found a couple of post advising to:

1. Edit wp-confing.php
2. Add `define('WP_HOME','https://{ec2-ip-address}');` `define('WP_SITEURL','https://{ec2-ip-address}');`
3. Restart apache with `sudo service httpd restart`

I tried that too but I get the same result.

**EDIT:**
The browser shows the following errors:

> (index):43 GET
> http://{my-ec2-ip}/wp-admin/{my-ec2-ip}/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,utils&ver=5.5.1
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) (index):522 GET
> http://{my-ec2-ip}/wp-admin/{my-ec2-ip}/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=hoverIntent&ver=5.5.1
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) (index):36 GET
> http://{my-ec2-ip}/wp-admin/{my-ec2-ip}/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.5.1
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) d @ (index):36 (anonymous) @
> (index):36 (anonymous) @ (index):36 (index):522 GET
> http://{my-ec2-ip}/wp-admin/{my-ec2-ip}/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=hoverIntent&ver=5.5.1
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) common.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2 Uncaught
> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
> at common.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2 (anonymous) @ common.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2 wp-util.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2 Uncaught
> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
> at wp-util.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2 (anonymous) @ wp-util.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2 site-health.min.js?ver=5.5.1:2 Uncaught
> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Now if you check the first line in the error you will notice the duplication:

```
http://{my-ec2-ip}/wp-admin/{my-ec2-ip}/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,utils&ver=5.5.1
```

Not sure why it's happening

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for any errors?

Comment: you are not importing css files properly, or the css doesn't exist anymore, or css path is wrong, or the website url is wrong.

Comment: added the browser log. The website url is correct because the homepage and login page gets loaded and displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this codes in wp-config

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it